# What parts of Warsaw, Poland have more risk of robberies?

Tags: safety, security, poland, warsaw

Is there any public place or neighborhood in Warsaw city, Poland known for robberies, that I should avoid after sunset?

Comment: Thieves do not usually advertise their existence, and they tend to switch places depending on supply and demand... If you fear theft, act accordingly and be careful at all times. Basic caution should get you by any place on earth..

Comment: Why do you think there are areas of Warsaw you should avoid? Have you read or heard rumors?

Comment: @Willeke, every city in the world has some areas where the concentration of crime is high. This is common sense.

Comment: [Warsaw](https://www.travelsafe-abroad.com/poland/warsaw/) is the same as anywhere else: pickpockets and other criminals focus on crowded places, railway stations, places with lots of clueless tourists, etc. It has a reputation as being reasonably safe, as a quick Google will tell you. I assume you're not planning on going too far from the main tourist areas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Presuming you're a tourist in Warsaw, the neighborhoods you're most likely to frequent are quite safe, even at night. Violent robberies which can be more common in parts of the U.S. aren't as big of a thing in Europe.

Most tourists would end up in the central districts of Śródmieście (the city center, which includes neighborhoods like Powiśle, the Old and New Towns and Muranów), Wola, Ochota and Mokotów, all of which are safe even at night. I've lived in Ochota and it's very quiet in the evening.

Some will say to avoid the eastern side of Warsaw, specifically Praga, which is less safe. However, during the day Praga is actually quite safe and it's a pleasant place to visit. Check out the Saska Kępa neighborhood when you get the chance to, as it's home to some very stately mansions and is known for its street art.

So long as you exercise common sense, as you should in any big city, you'll be fine.